Remove everything string after and including the nth occurence in a text
Admitting that these regex questions have been asked before, I'm still struggling in getting a working solution (even after consulting ChatGPT).
Taking the following example: text <- c("test1", "test2 | ", "test3 | test3 | test 3", "test4 | test4 | test 4 | test4") I want to remove all text beginning from the n-th (in my case second) occurence of " | ".
So the output should be: output <- c("test1", "test2 | ", "test3 | test3", "test4 | test4")
I got it working for the case when there are up to two " | " texts with str_remove(text, "( \\| [^\\|]+$)"), but this doesn't generalize for cases with more then two occurences of this matching pattern.

"even after consulting ChatGPT". Humour is discouraged at SO.

Don't underestimate ChatGPT. Its first two attempts are usually wrong, but for some tasks its results are shockingly good.

You can use
library(stringr)
n <- 2
str_replace(text, paste0("^(.*?(?: \\| .*?){", n-1, "}) \\| .*"), "\\1")

where

 \|  is your delimiter
.*? matches any text (other than line break chars, add (?s) at the start of the pattern to make it match across lines)
str_replace is required to keep the first group value after removing the match value.

See the R demo online (and here is the resulting regex demo).

Incredible. I wish I understood just half of the regex but this works perfectly and is also considerably faster thany my current workaround (which is to split the string by " | ", then collect the first two groups, glue them together again with " | " follwed by some final NA polishing.

Another idea is to use base R function sub with such pattern.
output <- sub('^([^|]*\\|[^|]*?)\\s*\\|.*', '\\1', text)

See this demo at regex101 or an R demo at tio.run
The desired part is captured by the first group which is also used as replacement. .* consumes the rest of the string (will be removed). Between the pipe-symbols a negated character class characters other than |. The lazy [^|]*? before \s*| is used to prevent from ending in a whitespace.
To adjust it to the nth occurence, replace [^|]*\\| with (?:[^|]*\\|){n} (regex101 demo with n=2). If this doesn't work due to lack of support for lazy quantifiers (demo works) attach ,perl=T.

A solution might be to extract the string of interest instead of removing the undesired parts. For this, you can use a regular expression that matches the three cases of interest, in descending order of length: [:graph:]+ \\| [:graph:]+, [:graph:]+ \\| or [:graph:]+.
library(stringr)
str_extract(text, "^([:graph:]+ \\| [:graph:]+|[:graph:]+ \\||[:graph:]+)")
[1] "test1"         "test2 |"       "test3 | test3" "test4 | test4"

